# Solidity Function Modifying Value Failing

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, truffle

Using Truffle Development framework (web3, react, and solidity) to test a simple smart contract. I have a basic function I am testing when I press a button on the UI, but it doesn't seem to be working the way I'd expect it. I expect the contract to increment the value and return true. Note, that the value is later being displayed on the front-end as this is what I was playing with. Code is below:

Solidity contract

```
    uint total = 0;

    function setTotalValue() public returns(bool) {

    total = total + 2;
    return true;
}
```

App.js

```
async modifyTotal() {

fantasyInstance.setKittyValue.call().then(function(res) {
  console.log(res); //THIS RETURNS FALSE TO THE CONSOLE
});
```

For clarification, modiftyTotal is called when an HTML button is clicked. The console statement returns a value of "false" and the actual total value doesn't seem to change ever. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JS code doesn’t match the contract code and you omitted the portion of code that retrieves the contact instance, but I’m going to guess your issue is you’re using `call` instead of `sendTransaction`. `call` executes the method in the local node without changing state. You should only use it for testing or constant functions. See the [web3js documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcall).

Comment: I'm a dummy! Completely forgot it would take gas to modify variables in the contract. Great point.

Comment: No worries. If this addressed your issue, please accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone viewing this post in the future, here is the proper way to 'call' a function using sendTransaction: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/how-to-call-my-contracts-function-using-sendtransaction